# I want to update multiple columns i tried it this way but unfortunately its not working can anyone help me out?

Tags: sql, sql-update, multiple-columns

```
UPDATE business
    SET business_id=4,contact=Mario Luigi,position=plumber,
    SET business_id=3,email=www.grankelly.org,
    SET business_id=2,contact=Homer Simpson,position=Purchasing Engineer,address=1234 Main St,city=Springfield,state=IL,Postal=19382,phone=555-555-5555,email=www.cajundelights-midwest.com,
    WHERE
```

Comment: You are missing single quotes around strings and `WHERE` conditions.

Comment: what is in your `where` clause?

Answer (score 0):

These need to be separate update statements because you can't update multiple records with different values.  For example, you're updating business_id to different values, so each of those statements needs to be a separate query.  You also need to put single quotes around your string values.

```
/*Query 1:*/
UPDATE business
        SET business_id=4,contact='Mario Luigi',position='plumber'
WHERE ...

/*Query 2:*/
UPDATE business
        SET business_id=3,email='www.grankelly.org' WHERE ...

/*Query 3*/
UPDATE business 
SET business_id=2,contact='Homer Simpson',position='Purchasing Engineer',address='1234 Main St',city='Springfield',[state]='IL',Postal='19382',phone='555-555-5555',email='www.cajundelights-midwest.com' WHERE ...
```